# Simple question about power

Tags: education

Please solve this question and describe it.
$$a^2+b^2+ab=b-a-1\Longrightarrow a^{1001}+b^{1001}=?$$
By Newton formula.

Comment: Please show what *you* have tried and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a^2+b^2+ab=b-a-1 \implies (a+b)^2+(a+1)^2+(b-1)^2=0 \implies a=-1,b=1$

Comment: Greattttttttttttttt.Thanks